# Inserting object with different values in a ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a JFrame where I insert some informations, these informations I send to a object called "macro". When I hit a JButton "macro" is insert in a ArrayList, called "listaJFP". When I enter with the first informations like, name "Murilo", id "1", and hit the button, my ArrayList receives the correct information, but when I try to insert another name like "Joao", id "2", my ArrayList receives in the first index [0] Joao, 2, and second index[1] Joao, 2. Instead of [0]Murilo,1 and [1]Joao,2. I looked for this problem and I saw someone talking about the reference of the object, in other words, when I change the values of my object "macro" at the same time the values of my ArrayList are changed. Can someone help me, please ? Thanks for the attention !

This is in my class JFramePrincipal:

```
Macro macro = new Macro();

private List<Macro> listaJFP = new ArrayList<Macro>();
```

This is in my JButton actionPerformed:

```
listaJFP.add(macro);

JFrameTabela jfT = new JFrameTabela(listaJFP);
```

I will try to put more code:

```
public class JFramePrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private List<Macro> listaJFP = new ArrayList<Macro>();
Macro macro = new Macro();
String[] arrayNodeName;
String[] listaVelocidade = new String[]{"1024", "1984"};
String[] listaSlot = new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
String[] listaModule86x0 = new String[]{"0", "1"};
String[] listaModule8609 = new String[]{"3", "4"};
String[] listaPort = new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"};
String[] listaPortFeGe = new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
String[] nodeType = new String[]{"8609", "8630", "8660"};

 private void jButtonGerarMacroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    try {
        if (jCheckBoxFSP.isSelected() == true) {
            macro.setVpnName(jFormattedTextFieldFSP.getValue().toString());
        } else if (jCheckBoxSP.isSelected() == true) {
            macro.setVpnName(jFormattedTextFieldSP.getValue().toString());
        }

        macro.velocidade = jComboBoxVelocidade.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (jTextVLAN.isEnabled() == true) {
            int vlanInt;
            boolean ok = false;
            vlanInt = Integer.parseInt(jTextVLAN.getText());
            do {
                if (vlanInt >= 1 && vlanInt <= 4094) {
                    macro.vlan = jTextVLAN.getText();
                    gerar();
                    jButtonExecutarMacro.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VLAN deve ser maior do que 0 e menor do que 4094", "Mensagem", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    jTextVLAN.grabFocus();
                    jButtonExecutarMacro.setEnabled(false);
                }
            } while (ok);
        } else {
            macro.vlan = null;
            gerar();
            jButtonExecutarMacro.setEnabled(true);
            jButtonGerarMacro.setEnabled(false);
        }


private void jButtonExibirResultadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
    if(jCheckBoxE1.isSelected() == true){
        listaJFP.add(macro);
        Macro macro = new Macro();
        JFrameTabela jfT = new JFrameTabela(listaJFP);
```

}

Comment: Seems like you are forgetting to copy the object at some point.  But it is hard to tell where without the GUI code.  If you want get answer faster please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you make sure to create a `new Macro` for every input from GUI.  It may be that you're adding the same macro everytime.

Comment: No. I am not creating a new Macro everytime. But my question is, where do I put this new Macro ? In the beginning of the class ? After listaJFP.add(macro); ? Where ?

Comment: Put it in your `actionPerformed()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure to `create a new Macro` for every input from GUI

You have to Create a new Macro like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Macro macro = new Macro();
    listaJFP.add(macro);
}
// so it create a totally new Macro object everytime
```

**Edit: After OP edit with more code**

You need to create to new Macro inside to the first ActionPerformed because that's where you're manipulating the data.  And why do you have two different actionperformed for a similar task?

Comment: When I put Macro macro = new Macro(); before the add, I insert in the list a null value.

Comment: Need to see more code.  Hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you put the `add` before the `new Macro`, where is the `macro` in `add(macro)` coming from.  That's what makes no sense at all.  A lot more relevant code is needed, in order for anyone to understand what's really going on. We can all guess but we may run into situations like this, where fixing one bug causes another bug.

Comment: You need to create to new Macro inside to the first ActionPerformed because that's where you're manipulating the data. And why do you have two different actionperformed for a similar task?

Comment: I do the Macro macro = new Macro(); at the beginning of the first actionPerformed ? or in the end ?

Comment: Think about it for a minute.  If you want to manipulate it, where do you think it should go?

Comment: Because I have to do more things inside the other one. I didnt put all the actionPerformed. Can you please tell me the exactly place of the first actionPerformed that I have to put the Macro macro = new Macro();

Comment: All of your `Macro` manipulating and `add` need to go inside the same actionPerformed. That's why I asked why do you have two.

Comment: Now I understand. I will try to modify

Comment: You don't need this at all in you `JFramePrincipal`: `Macro macro = new Macro();`.  It should go inside the actionPerformed.  And decide which `actionPerformed` is going to be the one to `create and add the macro`.  You can't have it seperate.

Comment: Ok. But I have to remove the Macro macro = new Macro(); from the beginning of the class ?

Comment: Yes, that's why you're getting the duplicate

Comment: I remove and then I add it only in the beginning of the actionPerformed and in the and of the actionPerformed after the listaJFP.add(macro);

Comment: Yes. In a perfect world, that's how it should be.

Comment: rsrsrsrs I will pray for this

Comment: You dont need the second Macro after the add

Comment: It`s going well now ! Thanks peeskillet !

Comment: Now I am having another problem rs rs. If I enter one value my JTable displays two lines, one with de correct value and the other blank

Comment: Did that happen before you made your original post?  And I don't know what your new code looks like, so it's hard to help.  You should really just stare at the code for awhile. It helps in the learning process.

Comment: I solve it rsrs, i was adding two times the macro inside the list.